# Prove that if $a\in G^n$ and $g\in G$ then $g^{-1}ag\in G^n$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

For all $a,b\in G$ there is: $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$.

Define $G^n=\{g^n\ |\ g\in G\}$. Prove that $G^n$ is a subgroup of $G$ and that

if $a\in G^n$ and $g\in G$ then $g^{-1}ag\in G^n$.

I managed to prove that $G^n$ is a subgroup of $G$ but I can't prove the latter.

Comment: $$g^{-1}h^ng=(g^{-1}hg)^n$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from $g^{-1} x^n g = (g^{-1} x g)^n$.

Comment: PS: This holds in *any* group. The condition $(ab)^n=a^n b^n$ is not needed.